# Hover styles are not applied in React-big-calendar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover, react-big-calendar

In the calendar cell, hover styles are not applied when hovering:
[image: cursor hover]
but if I change the element state to hover through devtools, then the styles are applied:
[image: force hover through devtools]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem simply by applying a higher z-index to the ".rbc-time-slot" class than to ".rbc-events-container".